# @RunAs and Role Propagation

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, roles

Glassfish-3.1.2.2.

I have 1 Servlet and 2 EJB in my project.

Servlet--------->Init--------------->Print

// EJB init code

```
@Stateless
@RunAs("SYSTEM")
@DeclareRoles({"SYSTEM"})
public class Init {

@Resource
EJBContext ejb;
@EJB
private Print print;

public void initialize() {

System.out.println("**********" + ejb.getCallerPrincipal().getName());
System.out.println("**********" + ejb.isCallerInRole("SYSTEM"));

print.printline();
}
}
```

// EJB Print code:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({"SYSTEM"})
public class Print {

@Resource
EJBContext ejb;

public void printline() {

System.out.println("**********" + ejb.getCallerPrincipal().getName());
System.out.println("*********" + ejb.isCallerInRole("SYSTEM"));

}
}
```

// Execution result:

```
INFO: **********ANONYMOUS (OK)
INFO: **********false (OK)

INFO: **********system (OK)
INFO: **********false (? )
```

Why Am I getting the second false (I am expecting true) ?

Mapping of web project and ejb project

```
  <security-role-mapping>
  <role-name>SYSTEM</role-name>
  <group-name>system</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I figure out the problem. Actually  in  the mapping the

'<'principal-name'>' username '< /'principal-name'>'

must be specified with the username associated to the group.